# mognoDB calculate average over a date range but my date is in ISO format and I need to match a day irrespective of exact time

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

**Goal --->** I want to calculate the daily average and also the average for a specific date range.

My date is in ISO format, so when I do the following aggregation it matches the exact date and then the average is wrong.

```js
const avg = await Model.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: '$date',
      avg: {$avg: '$quantityInLitres'},
    }
  }
])
```

**Documents --->**

```js
[
  {
    date: 2022-05-25T18:30:00.000+00:00,
    quantityInLitres: 30
  },
  {
    date: 2022-07-09T11:32:11.543+00:00,
    quantityInLitres: 10
  },
  {
    date: 22022-07-09T11:32:35.747+00:00,
    quantityInLitres: 20
  }
]
```

Here average should be (30 + 10 + 20 / 2) = 30 but it returns 20.

Also How to calculate a monthly average.

I really appreciate your time & Thanks In Advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To elaborate on why your original query returns an average of 20 rather than an average of 30 like you're expecting, It's because the average of those three numbers *IS* 20.

But I'm assuming the behaviour you want is to sum the litres for each day and then calculate the average.

<strike>Note that my below answer takes into consideration that for whatever reason you're needing to store the date as a string however, that string representing a date is assumed always valid. If the date is invalid the below solution will error which is the case in your example data set e.g. `date: "22022-07-09T11:32:35.747+00:00"`.</strike>

So, to get the average for the entire data set you can use:

```
const avg = await Model.aggregate([
  {$group: {
    _id: {year: {$year: '$date'}, day: {$dayOfYear:  '$date'}},
    sum: {$sum: '$quantityInLitres'}
  }},
  {$group: {
    _id: null,
    avg: {$avg: '$sum'}
  }}
]);
```

Where the first $group stage in the pipeline is grouping by both the year *and* the day, and summing those values.
And the second $group stage in the pipeline is grouping everything and then calculating the average.

And to get the average for each month of each year, you can use:

```
const avg = await Model.aggregate([
  {$group: {
    _id: {year: {$year: '$date'}, day: {$dayOfYear: '$date'}},
    sum: {$sum: '$quantityInLitres'},
    date: {$first: '$date'}
  }},
  {$group: {
    _id: {year: '$_id.year', month: {$month: '$date'}},
    avg: {$avg: '$sum'}
  }}
]);
```

Where the first $group stage in the pipeline is doing the same as the first query but also keeping the date field.
And then the second $group stage in the pipeline is grouping by the year *and* the month, and then calculating the average.

Comment: Hey Sam, My date is stored in ISO date format, I've added double quotes around them simply so that stack overflow can apply the colour scheme correctly, Sorry I've removed them now. Now the solution is going to be different, or the same(considering the ISO date format)? Also Should I consider saving date in string format as `7/10/2022` how much help this will provide in performance as we can eliminate the use of additional aggregation operators?

Comment: Not having to parse them from a string to a date will certainly help the performance of the query, so I think you should leave them as bson dates as you have now, sorry for the confusion! I've updated my answer to remove the need for parsing strings to dates.

Comment: Instead of `_id: {year: {$year: '$date'}, day: {$dayOfYear:  '$date'}` you can also use `_id: { $dateTrunc: { date: '$date', unit: 'day' } }` resp. `... unit: 'month'`

Comment: Hey Sam,  answer for monthly average can be more simplified. We don't need to group be day in the first place.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit, I've tested using `$dateTrunc` (1) operator and using the one mentioned in answer (`year: { $year: '$date' }, day: { $dayOfYear: '$date' }` (2)) over a 9.9Million documents and the second one turns out to be two times faster...

Comment: I would expect the same speed. Try again, when you execute a query multiple times, then data might be read from cache rather than from disk (which is slower, of course)

Comment: tried it... Maybe the issue is that I am using local instance and not atlas or something!

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit, For calculating averages in the above example we are only considering days where the data is present. For example, if data for some date is not present then that will not be considered( No documents will be grouped). So now the question is How to calculate averages and consider days where no data is present!

Comment: Please open a new question for that. In upcoming MongoDB 6.0 you can use [$densify](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/upcoming/reference/operator/aggregation/densify/#mongodb-pipeline-pipe.-densify) In current release you will have to write some more code.